# Passing user data after login between windows in Python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have problem with passing dictionary between windows in Tkinter. After successful login I want to create dictionary, in which data of the logged-in user will be stored. I would like dictionary to be available in every window of the program. I tried to do it this way:

```
import tkinter as tk  # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont  # python 3

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, Window2, Window1):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.discUserInfo = {}
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack()

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Login:")
        label2.pack()
        label2.place()

        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e1.pack()
        self.e1.place()

        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Password:")
        label3.pack()
        label3.place()
        self.e2 = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.e2.pack()
        self.e2.place()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                            command=self._login_btn_clicked,width = 25)
        button1.pack()
        button1.place()
    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        ### after verifying the login data in database, it creates a dictionary with the user's data ( userId,name,lastName ...)
        self.discUserInfo['name'] ='Joe'
        self.discUserInfo['userId'] =1
        self.controller.show_frame("Window1")


class Window2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="window 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Tset",
                                 command=self.onClick, width=42,bg="#C44041")
        button1.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                               command=lambda : controller.show_frame("Window1"), width=42, bg="#C44041")
        button3.pack()

    def onClick(self):
        print (self.discUserInfo)

class Window1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="window 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Next",
                                   command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Window2"), width=42)
        button1.pack()
        button1.place()

        ##################################################
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Test",
                                 command=self.getAlocationData, width=42)

        button2.pack()
        button2.place()
    def getAlocationData(self):
        print(self.discUserInfo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 650))
    app.mainloop()
```

But python shows this error:

> print(self.discUserInfo) AttributeError: 'Window1' object has no
>   attribute 'discUserInfo'.

I tried to create a global dictionary.But working only in some one windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the dictionary in the controller (SampleApp) then all other windows could access it via self.controller.discUserInfo. The following is not tested, but something like this may work.

```
 class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.discUserInfo = {}
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, Window2, Window1):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack()

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Login:")
        label2.pack()
        label2.place()

        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e1.pack()
        self.e1.place()

        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Password:")
        label3.pack()
        label3.place()
        self.e2 = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.e2.pack()
        self.e2.place()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                            command=self._login_btn_clicked,width = 25)
        button1.pack()
        button1.place()
    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        ### after verifying the login data in database, it creates a dictionary with the user's data ( userId,name,lastName ...)
        self.controller.discUserInfo['name'] ='Joe'
        self.controller.discUserInfo['userId'] =1
        self.controller.show_frame("Window1")


class Window2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="window 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Tset",
                                 command=self.onClick, width=42,bg="#C44041")
        button1.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                               command=lambda : controller.show_frame("Window1"), width=42, bg="#C44041")
        button3.pack()

    def onClick(self):
        print (self.controller.discUserInfo)

class Window1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="window 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Next",
                                   command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Window2"), width=42)
        button1.pack()
        button1.place()

        ##################################################
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Test",
                                 command=self.getAlocationData, width=42)

        button2.pack()
        button2.place()
    def getAlocationData(self):
        print(self.controller.discUserInfo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 650))
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works. I am very grateful :)

Comment: No problem Andersi